# A Group of people: A simple word

Tags: word, knowledge

This word describes a group of people

> Take the last letter out: A person with some authority
>
> Take the last two letters out: Same person
>
> Take the last three letters out: Same person
>
> Take the last four letters out: A fictional person with authority

Can you guess?

Comment: Same person means the same person with authority? Or those two are the same person when you take a letter out? +1 +favorite

Comment: same person with authority. Essentially after you remove the last, 2 last and 3 last letters it is describing the same person (with authority)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A conceivable answer is

> mamas, giving mama (authority over children), with shortenings mam and ma.

Removing the last four letters produces

> M - the fictional head of MI6, who is James Bond's boss.